# Remove Part of String Before the Last Forward Slash

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

The program I am currently working on retrieves URLs from a website and puts them into a list. What I want to get is the last section of the URL.

So, if the first element in my list of URLs is `"https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/interpreter.html"` I would want to remove everything before `"interpreter.html"`.

Is there a function, library, or regex I could use to make this happen? I've looked at other Stack Overflow posts but the solutions don't seem to work.

These are two of my several attempts:

```
for link in link_list:
   file_names.append(link.replace('/[^/]*$',''))
print(file_names)
```

&

```
for link in link_list:
   file_names.append(link.rpartition('//')[-1])
print(file_names)
```

Comment: How do you know they aren't working? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: @Kevin The output is not correct.

Comment: Why is your `rpartition()` attempt splitting on backslash instead of forward slash?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Sorry. Just fixed it

Comment: Now it's splitting on a pair of forward slashes instead of a single one (the forward slash doesn't need to be escaped).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I tested with a single and double forward slash, and it still does not work. Testing some of the answers below now.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried `'https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/interpreter.html'.rpartition('/')[-1]` and it returned `'interpreter.html'` as expected.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes. I'm sure. For some reason it doesn't work in my program. That's odd...

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that the elements in `link_list` aren't what you think they are. Try printing them to check whether they match your expectations.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Hmm.. well I just deleted everything and rewrote it with your edit. It works now! That's odd. I'll have to check that out, because it didn't work before...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Have a look at [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit).

```
>>> s = 'https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/interpreter.html'
>>> s.rsplit('/',1)
['https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial', 'interpreter.html']
>>> s.rsplit('/',1)[1]
'interpreter.html'
```

And to use RegEx

```
>>> re.search(r'(.*)/(.*)',s).group(2)
'interpreter.html'
```

Then match the 2nd group which lies between the last `/` and the end of String. This is a greedy usage of the greedy technique in RegEx.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/yeVim42ouXswpzZm)

*Small Note* - The problem with `link.rpartition('//')[-1]` in your code is that you are trying to match `//` and not `/`. So remove the extra `/` as in `link.rpartition('/')[-1]`.

Answer (score 14):

That doesn't need regex.

```
import os

for link in link_list:
    file_names.append(os.path.basename(link))
```

Comment: Yep- that's fast too. This is the stronger way to parse those types of strings, imo

Answer (score 9):

You can use [rpartition()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition):

```
>>> s = 'https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/interpreter.html'
>>> s.rpartition('/')
('https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial', '/', 'interpreter.html')
```

And take the last part of the 3 element tuple that is returned:

```
>>> s.rpartition('/')[2]
'interpreter.html'
```

Comment: Possibly because splitting on `/` won't work if the string uses backslashes as file structure delimiters... but that's not an issue for URLs, so I'm not sure.

Comment: This is amazing!

Answer (score 2):

Just use string.split:

```
url = "/some/url/with/a/file.html"

print url.split("/")[-1]

# Result should be "file.html"
```

split gives you an array of strings that were separated by "/".  The [-1] gives you the last element in the array, which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more general, regex way of doing this:

```
    re.sub(r'^.+/([^/]+)$', r'\1', "http://test.org/3/files/interpreter.html")
    'interpreter.html'
```

Comment: What does the first part mean? ```re.sub(r'^.+/([^/]+)$',...)```. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you plan to use regex

```
 for link in link_list:
    file_names.append(link.replace('.*/',''))
 print(file_names)
```