# S3 Python List nested sub directories

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

How can I list sub directories within a Prefix of a S3 bucket using boto3 python?

For example, if I have bucket named `test` with following structure:

```
test/abc/def/1/a.gz
test/abc/def/2/b.gz
test/abc/ghi/1/a.gz
```

Then I want the output as:

```
test/abc/def/1
test/abc/def/2
test/abc/ghi/1
```

Answer (score 1):

Folders/subdirectories don't actually exist in S3. Instead, they form part of the filename (`Key`) of an object.

Therefore, just grab the Key up to the last slash:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name = 'ap-southeast-2')

response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket')

# If the Key contains a slash, store the Key up to the last slash
folders = set(object['Key'][:object['Key'].rfind('/')+1] for object in response['Contents'] if '/' in object['Key'])

# Print the results
print('\n'.join(sorted(folders)))
```

See also: [Determine if folder or file key - Boto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54451319/174777)