# S3 boto3 list directories only

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have below hierarchy in S3 and would like to retrieve only subfolders type information excluding files that ends in .txt (basically exclude filenames and retrieve only prefixes/folders).

```
--folder1/subfolder1/item1.txt
--folder1/subfolder1/item11.txt
--folder1/subfolder2/item2.txt
--folder1/subfolder2/item21.txt
--folder1/subfolder3/item3.txt
--folder1/subfolder3/subfolder31/item311.txt
```

Desired Output:

```
--folder1/subfolder1
--folder1/subfolder2
--folder1/subfolder3/subfolder31
```

I understand that there is no folders/subfolders in S3 but all are keys.

I tried below code but it is displaying all information including filenames like `item1.txt`

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('s3-bucketname')
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')


objs = list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='folder1/'))
for i in range(0, len(objs)):
    print(objs[i].key)
```

Any recommendation to get below output?

```
--folder1/subfolder1
--folder1/subfolder2
--folder1/subfolder3/subfolder31
```

Comment: Further examples: [How to get ALL subdirectories, all levels deep except files in AWS S3 with python boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69566759/174777) and [S3 Python List nested sub directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54628897/174777)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, S3 doesn't really have a concept of folders, so to get what you want, in a sense, you need to recreate it.

One option is to list all of the objects in the bucket, and construct the folder, or prefix, of each object, and operate on new names as you run across them:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('s3-bucketname')
shown = set()
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='folder1/'):
    prefix = "/".join(obj.key.split("/")[:-1])
    if len(prefix) and prefix not in shown:
        shown.add(prefix)
        print(prefix + "/")
```

Comment: thank you. Is there an easy way to send this   print(prefix + "/") to a csv file in S3 ?  i think my output is getting more than 1000 records and would just want to store it in a file.