# I am trying to find a way to count all of the objects within an s3 bucket using Amazon's AWS lambda using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to find a way to count all of the objects within an s3 bucket using Amazon's AWS lambda using python

```
import os
import boto3

os.environ['input_bucket'] = 'demo-bucket-ak'

s3_client = boto3.client("s3") # Importing s3 client 

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    
    print("Loading the function...")

    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=os.environ['input_bucket'])
    s3_bucket = os.environ['input_bucket']
    json_file = response['Contents'][0]['Key']
    print(s3_bucket)
    print(json_file)
```

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54656455/get-count-of-objects-in-a-specific-s3-folder-using-boto3. There you will find examples and also additional hints about pagination, etc.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2), your `response` object should already contain the information needed in `response[keyCount]`, if there are less than 1.000 objects.