# Remove empty folder in S3 bucket via CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I have about 8K folders in an S3 bucket. Some of them are "empty" (does not have objects with its name prefix) and some are "not empty".

How I can programmatically detect such "empty" folder in the bucket and remove it.

Yes, I know there is no concept of a folder in a bucket - it just names.

Comment: See: [Determine if folder or file key - Boto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54451319/174777)

Answer (score 0):

An empty folder in the context of S3 is a zero-sized S3 object whose key ends with your folder separator, typically `/`, for example `images/cats/`.

If the applications that use this S3 bucket don't strictly need these folder objects but instead can infer the presence of a folder structure from the presence of file objects e.g. infer the folder `images/dogs/` when they see the file `images/dogs/terrier.png`, then one solution to remove all empty folders would be to simply enumerate all objects that end in `/` and then delete all of those that are zero-sized. That would remove *all* folder objects.

If the applications do need these folder objects to remain for non-empty folders, then you'd do something different. For example, enumerate all S3 objects in the bucket, pull out those that represent folders (zero-sized, ending in `/`) and then see if that same prefix is present in any other, non-folder object.

Also, if you find that enumerating the entire bucket's contents becomes problematic (for example, if you have millions of objects) then you might consider using an S3 Inventory report to drive your process.